# E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!! (parcel size = 324)

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with firebase and  i'm trying to click the login button but the home page doesn't show up it just says "please waiting!!!" run forever like:
[image]
. I can't find a solution to fix it. Help me please.
My realtime Database:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ckzM7NitXdPKGdIG6dbAv0IWhl1WgtZk/view?usp=sharing

In SignIn Class:

```
package com.example.eatit_new;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.eatit_new.Common.Common;
import com.example.eatit_new.Model.User;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.example.eatit_new.databinding.ActivitySignInBinding;
import com.google.firebase.auth.OAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editPhone, editPassword;
    Button btnSignIn;
@Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);


        editPassword=(MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.editPassword);

        editPhone= (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.editPhone);
        btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);

        //init Database
    final FirebaseDatabase database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference table_user=database.getReference("User");

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignIn.this);
            mDialog.setMessage("Please waiting....");
            mDialog.show();

            table_user.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //Check if user not exist in database

                    if (dataSnapshot.child(editPhone.getText().toString()).exists()) {

                        //Get User Information
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        User user = dataSnapshot.child(editPhone.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
                        if (user.getPassword().equals(editPassword.getText().toString())) {

                            Intent homeIntent= new Intent(SignIn.this,Home.class);
                            Common.currentUser= user;
                            startActivity(homeIntent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Wrong password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "User not exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Error In Run:

```
 
W/Parcel: Expecting binder but got null!
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 324)
W/GmsClient: IGmsServiceBroker.getService failed
    android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died, but this could also be caused by running out of binder buffe
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.getService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:8)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient.getRemoteService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:14)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$LegacyClientCallbackAdapter.onReportServiceBinding(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzg.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zza.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzc.zze(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:31)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
D/FA: Service connection suspended
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 6704
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 31916685
D/AutofillManager: Fill dialog is enabled:false, hints=[]
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 31916803
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
W/Parcel: Expecting binder but got null!
D/TrafficStats: tagSocket(107) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171228096; UID 10157; state: ENABLED
W/Parcel: Expecting binder but got null!
D/EGL_emulation: app_time_stats: avg=30.81ms min=2.94ms max=450.90ms count=28
```

Comment: you only `dismiss` that dialog `if (dataSnapshot.child(editPhone.getText().toString()).exists())`. Debug your application and see if that ever turns out to be `true`.

Comment: hmmm it not work for me.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400** (four hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).